# std::shared_ptr upcasting to base class - best method?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Which conversion is better, and what is the difference?

```
class Base
{};

class Derived : public Base, public std::enable_shared_from_this<Derived>
{};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr1 = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Base>(std::shared_ptr<Derived>(new Derived())); // version 1
    std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr2 = std::shared_ptr<Derived>(new Derived()); // version 2
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The second would be preferred in this case. The first requires an unnecessary `dynamic_cast`. The second relies on the implicit conversion from `Derived*` to `Base*`.

Comment: In that case when should I use std::dynamic_pointer_cast? I've thought that it is for cases like this one.

Comment: `dynamic_pointer_cast` is for a checked cast from `Base` to `Derived`.

Comment: You use `dynamic_pointer_cast` in the same situations as you would use `dynamic_cast`, so you should never use it to upcast, because upcasting doesn't need a run-time check. You know with 100% certainty that every `Derived` has a `Base` base class and so `Derived*` can be safely converted to `Base*`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As in other use cases of `shared_ptr`, you should prefer using `make_shared` instead of constructing the `shared_ptr` manually:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr2 = std::make_shared<Derived>();
```

This is essentially your version 2, plus [the various benefits of `make_shared`](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/).

Version 1 does a bunch of unnecessary stuff: First you construct a temporary `shared_ptr<Derived>`, then you `dynamic_cast` its contents to a base class pointer (while a `static_cast` would be sufficient here) and then you store that pointer in a different `shared_ptr<Base>`. So you have a lot of unnecessary runtime operations, but no benefits regarding type safety over Version 2.

Answer (score 3):

The second one would make more sense, as it is the exact transposition of what would be done with a real pointer while avoiding the use of an explicit cast, i.e.

```
Base* ptr = new Derived();
```

Another option would be using [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) specifying `Derived` as template parameter, i.e.:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr2 = std::make_shared<Derived>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems the most obvious answer has not been mentioned so I'll add that for completeness.

You don't need a cast, the best way to accomplish that is the following:

```
#include <memory>

class Base 
{};

class Derived : public Base, public std::enable_shared_from_this<Derived>
{};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
     std::shared_ptr<Derived> ptr1 = std::make_shared<Derived>();
     std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr2 = ptr1; // no CAST NEEDED HERE AS YOU SEE :)
     return 0;
}
```

deriving from `enable_shared_from_this` does not change anything in this case. you could as well use the following classes (making your code slightly more readable)

```
class Base 
{};

class Derived: public Base
{};
```

Of course I don't know your implementation details, so it is very possible you still need deriving from `enable_shared_from_this`

Comment: enable_shared_from_this will just combine Derived object and shared_ptr counters in the same memory allocation unit.
This is a small performance enhancement, not important in this particular case.

Comment: Probably not performance, but I think it is more clear in this way. Good point though

Comment: I was a bit incorrect. enable_shared_from_this also gives possibility to cast this to shared_ptr in any member function.