# Convert child class to parent C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, queue

I have the following parent class:

```
namespace dataserver {
class Request_manager {
public:
    class Ticket {
    public:
        virtual void start(){};
        virtual ~Ticket();
        explicit Ticket(System_time start_time);

    protected:

        System_time const& start_time() const { return m_start_time; }
        System_time m_start_time;

    private:
        std::time_t m_key;
        std::size_t m_request_id;
    };

    static int num_connected() { return m_connected; }

private:
    static int m_connected;
};
} // namespace dataserver
#endif // _DATASERVER_REQUEST_MANAGER_H_
```

And a child class:

```
namespace dataserver {
namespace pointdata {

class Ticket : Request_manager::Ticket,
               public std::enable_shared_from_this<Ticket> {
public:
    Ticket(Batch_request rq, Data_interface* dataserver,
           xxx::service::Service_ticket tix, System_time start_time);

    void start();

private:

    void serialize(std::vector<Future<Group_result>> data_f);
    void failed(std::exception_ptr error);
};
}
} // namespace dataserver::pointdata

#endif // _DATASERVER_POINTDATA_TICKET_H_
```

I have other child classes from Request_manager and I want to save them in a queue altogether. Assume I do not need to create any object of the parent class. To accomplish that I have a class `Tickets_Queue`

```
using namespace dataserver;

class Tickets_Queue{

    private:
        std::queue <std::shared_ptr<Request_manager::Ticket>> m_ticket_queue;

    public:
        Tickets_Queue();
        ~Tickets_Queue();
        void push(std::shared_ptr<Request_manager::Ticket> ticket);

};

#endif /* _TICKETS_QUEUE_H_ */
```

To push the different type of childs I do:

```
std::shared_ptr<Request_manager::Ticket> ticket = std::make_shared<Ticket>(...,
                                           ..., ..., ...);
ticket_queue_->push(ticket);
```

This gives me error:

```
error: conversion from ‘std::shared_ptr<dataserver::pointdata::Ticket>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::shared_ptr<dataserver::Request_manager::Ticket>’ requested
```

**EDIT**

Trying this:
[std::shared_ptr upcasting to base class - best method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018774/stdshared-ptr-upcasting-to-base-class-best-method)
still gives me the same error:

```
error: conversion from ‘std::shared_ptr<dataserver::pointdata::Ticket>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::shared_ptr<dataserver::Request_manager::Ticket>’ requested
```

Comment: You mean upcasting?

Comment: Yes, but I want that afterwards when I get it from the Queue I can call the child start() method

Comment: Make sure there are no circular ```#include```s in your project. This may seem completely unrelated but sometimes the compiler gives really weird errors when you try to convert a ```shared_ptr``` to a type it doesn't know.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be with private inheritance.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {};

class B: public A {}; //<-- fails to compile if "public" is omitted

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<A> a(new B);
}
```